# Is the 5 euro coin accepted anywhere?

Tags: europe, legal, money

Three years ago I went to the post office in a big city in France, there I received change back after I paid for something. I didn't look at it first but later on I discovered that I received a €5 coin. EUROS not francs.

Two years later in a medium city in Germany I went into a shop to buy food. There I gave money to pay for my food including the €5 coin. The shop assistant looked at it then said:

> We only accept euros here…
>
> I answered: it is euros look closer
>
> He answered after looking again: sorry we don't accept such payments

I found this on the web [in French](http://www.tuxboard.com/piece-de-5-euros-15-euros-et-100-euros-photos/)

Can I pay with a €5 coin? Or is it only for collections? Was the shop assistant doing the right or the wrong thing?

Comment: exaclty same as in the photo yes

Comment: @DCTLib Not true. There's a EU directive that means you *have to* accept up to 50 euro coins. In Germany shops are allowed to not accept large banknotes (200 and 500€) though as long as they clearly indicate this and the bill isn't appropriate to the bill (i.e. paying a 450€ bill with a 500€ note is fine, but paying for 60€ isn't), although that's a somewhat legal grey zone. In Austria on the other hand the rule is stricter, but paying a 3€ bill with a 500€ note wouldn't fly either (and there's a big difference between what's legal and reality obviously)

Comment: There are no 5 euro coins. The coins have values 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 1.00 and 2.00.

Comment: @Voo: Deleted my comment, as the legal situation seems to have changed in some respects with the introduction of the Euro.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem There are 5€ coins allright, the OP got one, I explained in details what they are and even provided a link. What's the point of your comment?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is indeed a (national) collector's coin. [It is legal tender in the country where it was issued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_gold_and_silver_commemorative_coins#Introduction), but not elsewhere in the eurozone. Even in its country of origin, I could imagine that many people would be surprised to receive one or perhaps even refuse to believe that it is genuine.

And looking at the photos you can find on the web, I must say that their design is strongly reminiscent of old Franc coinage, which would only add to the confusion.

I can add that I have been living in the eurozone since it was created and even worked as a waiter for some time (during which time I have seen many banknotes and coins…) but I have never seen such a coin.

By contrast, [€2 commemorative coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%82%AC2_commemorative_coins) should be accepted and do circulate widely.

Comment: Fascinating. nb In the U.S. you may rarely receive a $2 note (Thomas Jefferson on the obverse) or various half-dollar and dollar coins. Some merchants refuse to accept them because they are extremely uncommon and thus annoying to handle (e.g. no slot in the cash tray). The $1 coins are deeply unpopular, and I only get them in New York City or as change from postal service vending machines. The $2 bill is so uncommon that there are periodic news stories about cashiers who reject them as fake.

Comment: Actually, several millions of 5 euros silver coins were issued, so they are not all that uncommon. (And, by the way, they are not going to be worth more than 5 euros in the foreseeable future.)

Comment: @fkraiem Unless maybe they run into the same issue that some of the small-denomination U.S. coins have had: after decades of inflation, the metal in the coin is worth more than the coin's face value. - haha

Comment: @reirab Excellent point.  In addition the rehypothecation of gold and silver futher decrease their value.  Will the EU still be around to see the day?

Comment: @fkraiem I don't know, what I can say is that they don't seem to circulate. Same thing for Vatican or San Marino coins. I don't have a total tally but a quick look at Wikipedia suggests that France issues a few tens of thousands gold and silver collectors' coins each year, compared to millions of commemorative coins (which I do see from time to time) and tens of millions of regular coins. There are over 100 billions of euro coins in total so even a few millions would be relatively rare.

Comment: Looking further, [here is one series](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euros_des_r%C3%A9gions) that appear to have been minted in larger numbers. Still haven't seen any of these coins, though.

Comment: There used to be change machines in some of SF's subway stations giving US $1 coins in return for paper $1 and $5, the better to pay fares. But with the switch to plastic passes (ours is "Clipper", London "Oyster Card", etc.) they pulled them out. Truth is, I found the $1 coin useful, more than the stupid penny.

Comment: @Andrew: wait, what? SF stations installed machines that accepted bills in order to compensate for the fact that other machines in the same stations didn't accept bills? Was it pork for the company that makes the machines or something?

Comment: @SteveJessop They are gone, but there used to be MUNI turnstiles that would take coins. First those were adapted for Clipper cards, and then replaced with gates operating only by cards. However, I used to use them (pre-Clipper) on the bus. The fareboxes accepted bills, but were often cranky about them, especially if wrinkled from my pocket. Coins, never an issue.

Comment: @Relaxed The gold coins are different, because they are made of gold and are issued in smaller numbers, they are likely to gain value relatively quickly, so people keep them safe and shiny for that purpose. The 5 euros silver coins, on the other hand, are unlikely to be of any value to a serious collector, so they do circulate (OP got one when receiving change at the post office, which seems a pretty mundane action, and I have held one twice as far as I can recall). Of course, they don't circulate outside of France since they are not legal tender there.

Comment: @fkraiem Well, I did read the question and I am not saying it never ever happens but I haven't seen them, and people I have asked since yesterday haven't either. Maybe gold coins are even rarer but that's beside the point.

Comment: and remember that such coins, even if minted in relatively large quantities, tend to become ever more rare in circulation as most end up in collections rapidly.